# How to change column type for a list of dataframe columns

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, casting

I'm trying to change the type of a list of columns for a Dataframe in Spark 1.6.0.

All the examples found so far however only allow casting for a single column (df.withColumn) or for all the columns in the dataframe:

```
val castedDF = filteredDf.columns.foldLeft(filteredDf)((filteredDf, c) => filteredDf.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("String")))
```

Is there any efficient, batch way of doing this for a list of columns in the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

There is  nothing wrong with `withColumn`* but you can use `select` if you prefer:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions col

val columnsToCast: Set[String]
val outputType: String = "string"

df.select(df.columns map (
  c => if(columnsToCast.contains(c)) col(c).cast(outputType) else col(c)
): _*)
```

* Execution plan will be the same for a single select as with chained `withColumn`.

Comment: `withColumn` and `select` are fully equivalent - execution plan will be _identical_.